# JSON Formatting of removing the index

Tags: javascript, json

I have this JSON array:

```
"locations": {
        "0": {
            "locationNo": "10014",
            "inventoryLocationNo": "10014"
        },
        "1": {
            "locationNo": "10499",
            "inventoryLocationNo": "10499"
        },
        "2": {
            "locationNo": "110868",
            "inventoryLocationNo": "110868"
        },
```

I want to remove this index part `("0", "1", "2")` from this array, rest all should be same.

Any suggestions?

The response should like like this:

```
"locations": {
    {
        "locationNo": "13137",
        "inventoryLocationNo": "13137"
   },
    {
        "locationNo": "15857",
        "inventoryLocationNo": "15857"
    },
    {
        "locationNo": "15903",
        "inventoryLocationNo": "15903"
    },
```

Comment: How should the output look like?

Comment: Your output's format is invalid.

Comment: "I have this JSON array"...based on what you've shown above, that's actually an object, although since you've got numeric property names you can, to a limited extent, use it the same way as an array. And yeah the desired output is not valid JSON.

Comment: Did you mean to ask for `"locations": [
    {
        "locationNo": "13137",
        "inventoryLocationNo": "13137"
   },
    {
        "locationNo": "15857",
        "inventoryLocationNo": "15857"
    },
    {
        "locationNo": "15903",
        "inventoryLocationNo": "15903"
    }]` ? That would be a valid JSON _array_

Answer (score 8):

Use `Object.values`:

```js
var obj = {
  "locations": {
        "0": {
            "locationNo": "10014",
            "inventoryLocationNo": "10014"
        },
        "1": {
            "locationNo": "10499",
            "inventoryLocationNo": "10499"
        },
        "2": {
            "locationNo": "110868",
            "inventoryLocationNo": "110868"
        }
     }
};

obj.locations = Object.values(obj.locations);

console.log(obj);
```

Or `Object.keys` if you cannot use Object.values:

```js
var obj = {
  "locations": {
        "0": {
            "locationNo": "10014",
            "inventoryLocationNo": "10014"
        },
        "1": {
            "locationNo": "10499",
            "inventoryLocationNo": "10499"
        },
        "2": {
            "locationNo": "110868",
            "inventoryLocationNo": "110868"
        }
     }
};

obj.locations = Object.keys(obj.locations).map(key => obj.locations[key]);

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Firstly, I am getting an error saying, Object.values is not a function.

Comment: secondly, when i run the code snippet I see the output, But i want to see a "{" brace instead of "[" after location. Refer my output

Comment: It cannot be a brace, with a brace, it's not a valid javascript object

Comment: @Vinu what you're asking for is not valid JSON, nor a valid JavaScript object. You can test it at https://jsonlint.com/ . If you don't understand the JSON / JavaScript format, you should study it some more. This answer is sensible and produces a useful array as the output.

Comment: I totally agree. It is not a valid JSON. I have already created a valid JSON. But testers are just comparing the output by just removing the Index numbers. So for that reason, i want to show the output without index numbers. Yes, I have already said them that it is not a valid JSON. But, for now i need your suggestions to create a invalid JSON. Thanks everyone for your responses.

Comment: @Vinu don't go along with people who are trying to test invalid things. Challenge them on it, and stick to your guns. If they don't understand, educate them. Why are they even removing the index numbers? What help is that to them? This seems like a workaround for a problem which does not need to exist.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to use spread operator

```
var obj = {
"locations": {
    "0": {
        "locationNo": "10014",
        "inventoryLocationNo": "10014"
    },
    "1": {
        "locationNo": "10499",
        "inventoryLocationNo": "10499"
    },
    "2": {
        "locationNo": "110868",
        "inventoryLocationNo": "110868"
    }
}
};

console.log(...Object.values(obj.locations))
```

Comment: it should be clear that this simply logs them as a series of separate objects. Not sure if that is the OP's intention. Also it's merely a way of displaying, it doesn't actually change the data structure.